# Maximal common divisor in polynomial quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

**Specific problem**

(If this part is too long, feel free to skip to the "Problem at general level" heading.)

Define
$$R = \frac{F[X, Y, Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n]}{<X^{q+1}-Y^q-Y>}\quad\text{where}\quad F = \mathrm{GF}(q^2).$$
Here $X^{q+1}-Y^q-Y$ is irreducible so that $R$ is an integral domain. (In fact $R$ is the coordinate ring of the Hermitian curve over the field $\mathrm{GF}(q^2)$ but extended with the variables $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$). Let $f, g \in R$.
My goal is to turn $f$ and $g$ relatively prime by dividing through their common factors.

Now from what I understand: in a Noetherian domain (which $R$ is), being a UFD is equivalent to being a GCD domain ([see #6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Equivalent_conditions_for_a_ring_to_be_a_UFD)).
I'm pretty sure $R$ is not a UFD, which means GCDs need not exist in it.
Hence, I should try to find any one maximal common divisor (MCD) of $f$ and $g$, so that I can divide through by it and turn $f$ and $g$ relatively prime
(in particular an algorithm that finds a non-trivial common factor will also do since one can repeatedly apply it to find an MCD).

As an addendum (in case it makes the problem easier):
in my specific situation I am only looking for common factors that contain at least one of the $Z_i$ variables. So it doesn't matter if the algorithm cannot find common factors containing only $X$ and $Y$. (But it's no problem if it *does* find them).

Now in order to solve this I framed the problem more generally.

**Problem at general level**

Define $$R = F[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n]/I$$ where $F$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal of $F[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$. In addition, $I$ is prime and finitely generated so that $R$ is an integral domain (and also Noetherian). Let $f, g \in R$. Then find any one maximal common divisor (MCD) of $f$ and $g$.

**What I tried**

1. Lifting: let $F, G \in F[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ be the lifted versions of $f, g$. Then one can show that if $F$ and $G$ have a common factor $D$ (which is easy to find), then $f$ and $g$ have the residue class of $D$ as their common factor. However, going the other way doesn't seem possible, so that it's possible for $F$ and $G$ to be relatively prime but not $f$ and $g$.
2. I know for finding the GCD in polynomial rings over a UFD, one can reduce the problem to finding the GCD in the UFD's field of fractions by only working on the primitive part of the polynomials (and [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)#General_version) mentions a generalization to GCD domains), but I'm not sure if or how this can be adapted to finding MCDs in integral domains.